# How to make an Extjs4.2 Chart filtered by a list

Tags: extjs, filter, charts, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I'm pretty new to web development and ExtJS, I've looked around for tutorials on more complex concepts but they are hard to find (Yes I've found the Sencha documentation but the only provide simple concepts)

I'm trying to make a dashboard for my application, in this dashboard I want a chart
that gives a detailed overview of my statistics. In order to accomplish this I am trying to add a custom filter for the chart by making a seperate list with that holds all the instances of the key, when selecting said instances from a list I want the chart to only display those selected instances.

The chart I made:

```
Ext.define('view.chart.LocationStatisticsPerMonth', {
    extend: 'Ext.chart.Chart',
    alias: 'widget.LocationStatisticsPerMonthChart',
    requires: [
        'store.LocationStatisticsStore',
        'store.TemplateStore',
        'view.TitleToolbar'
    ],

    constructor: function () {
        this.store = Ext.create('store.LocationStatisticsStore', {
            autoLoad: true, sorters: [{
                property: 'YearMonth',
                direction: 'ASC'
            }]
        });
        this.store.getProxy().api.read = ServerControllers.Dashboard.LocationStatisticsPerMonth;
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    animate: true,
    shadow: true,
    border: true,

    legend: {
        position: 'right'
    },

    axes: [{
        type: 'Numeric',
        position: 'left',
        fields: ['TotalCount'],
        title: false,
        grid: true,
        label: {
            renderer: function (v) {
                return String(v);
            }
        }
    }, {
        type: 'Category',
        position: 'bottom',
        fields: ['Location_Id'],
        title: false,
        label: {
            rotate: {
                degrees: 315
            }


        }


    }],


    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        axis: 'left',
        gutter: 80,
        xField: ['Location_Id'],
        yField: ['TotalCount'],

        tips: {
            trackMouse: true,
            width: 125,
            height: 28,
            renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
                this.setTitle(String('Visitors: '+item.value[1]));
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

My Store

```
Ext.define('store.LocationStatisticsStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: ['model.LocationStatistics'],
    model: 'model.LocationStatistics',
    autoLoad: false,
    remoteSort: false,
    remoteFilter: false,
    filterOnLoad: true,
    sorters: [{
        property: ['YearMonth' , 'Location_Id'],
        direction: 'DESC'
    }],
    proxy: {
        type: 'direct',
        paramOrder: [],
        api: {
            read: ServerControllers.Reports.GetLocationStatisticsPerMonth
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            totalProperty: 'totalRecords',
            successProperty: 'success',
            messageProperty: 'msg'
        }
    }
});
```

My Model:

```
Ext.define('model.LocationStatistics', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: ['Location_Id'],
    fields: [
        { name: 'YearMonth', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'Location_Id', type: 'int' },
    { name: 'Year', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'Month', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'TotalCount', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'AverageCountPerDay', type: 'int' }
    ]

});
```

Would anyone be so kind as to explain this concept to me, link a tutorial or provide me an example of how to go about doing this?

Help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: the panel that this is contained in:

```
 Ext.define('view.panel.DashboardStatisticsPanel', {
    extend    : 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias    : 'widget.DashboardStatisticsPanel',
    requires : [
        'Ext.layout.container.Column',
        'view.chart.LocationStatisticsPerMonth'
    ],
    plain: true,
    border: false,
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        padding: '10 10 10 10'
    },



    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        layout: 'fit',
        border: true,
        flex: 1,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            layout: 'anchor',
            border: true,
            overflowX: 'scroll',
            height: 400,


            dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            dock: 'top',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'label',
                text: 'Select Date',
                padding: '0 0 0 10'
            },


                {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                displayField: 'YearMonth',
                emptyText: 'Select Date ',
                queryMode: 'local',
                padding: '0 0 0 10',
                store: function (btn) {
                    btn.up('panel').down('LocationStatisticsPerMonthChart').getStore();
                },
                valueField: 'YearMonth',

            }]
        }]
            /*tbar: [{


                text: 'September Only',
                handler: function (btn) {
                    var store = btn.up('panel').down('LocationStatisticsPerMonthChart').getStore();
                    store.clearFilter();
                    Ext.defer(function (btn) {
                        store.filter("Month", 9);
                    }, 300);
                }





            }]*/,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'LocationStatisticsPerMonthChart',
                itemId: 'LocationStatisticsPerMonthChart',
                anchor: '2000, -10',
                //height: 400,
               // width: 2000,
            }]

        }],
        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'TitleToolbar',
            dock: 'top',
            title: Resources.t('RegistrationsPerUnit'),
            items: ['->', {
                iconCls: 'iconRefresh',
                itemId: 'refresh',
                scope: this,
                handler: function (btn) {
                    var store = btn.up('panel').down('LocationStatisticsPerMonthChart').getStore();
                    //store.removeAll();
                    store.load();
                }
            }]
        }]


    }] 


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use a function, I'll give you an example:

We have a store, let's call it StoreA, and another store StoreB

```
var storeA = something.getStore();
var storeB = somethingElse.getStore();

storeA.filterBy(function(record) {
    return storeB.find("name", record.data.name) != -1; 
});
```

So basicly in this example, if the name is in storeB (find returns an index), it will filter it out from storeA's contents.

Unfortunately, you will have to re-do the exact same filter every time a new record is added or updated... so what I do is bind a function that does this to the load, update, delete, etc.. events.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to filter the related data store. To accomplish this use the **[filter](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filter)** method as follows:

```
chart.store.filter("Month", 10);
```

You can always remove the filtering on the store by calling **[clearFilter](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-clearFilter)** store's method,

```
chart.store.clearFilter();
```

*Take into account that you need to remove previous filters when applying new ones otherwise the each new applied filter will stack with the current ones*

You can see a small example based on your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/overlordhammer/MFf6X/). Hope it helps you to solve your problem.

Comment: Not exactly what I had in mind since I was attempting on using a seperatly populated list in a seperate window but I'll try and mess around with this a bit and see if I can make it work. I'll keep this posted on my progress.

Comment: Do you want to use the list for filtering purposes? (e.g. a list of months / years you want to show on the chart) Or you want to use the list as data source for the chart itself (e.g. the list of records that match a filtering criteria)

Comment: I've added a new snippet to the top, Unfortunately I'm bound to a certain file structure and I'm having difficulties targeting the chart from the toolbar for the filter options. Any suggestions?

Comment: I indeed want to use the list as a filter, I am aiming to have two lists, one of them containing all Locations and the other one containing the Location I want shown on the chart.

Comment: When you talk about _filtering by location_ do you want to filter the data using the **Location_Id** field defined at your **LocationStatistics** model? If yes that doesn't make too much sense to me, since the field is marked as **idProperty** meaning that you will only have a single entry for each location value at most.

Comment: I want to be able to exclude specific entries from being drawn onto the chart, say as if they weren't in the store at all.

Comment: Well, I still think that the best option is the filter method on the store, that way the view will show only filtered records, may be you want to use the same store to show the full list of records in another view, that's why you don't want to apply the filter on the store in first place. If that is the reason I would strongly advice you just to have two stores with the same source (one filtered and the other with the full content) –

Comment: Going with your suggestion I am now trying to use filters to further format the chart, I've updated the Panel and am now trying to filter out specific YearMonth values using a combobox, alas I'm not having much luck referencing the chart store. any tips?

Comment: Are you having trouble on selecting the chart (and its store) from the combobox event handler? Can you supply a sample code of that?